# Strange code sequence <80>ýa <80>ý` recorded with -w

Tags: terminal, original-vim

I was noticing when I exit Insert Mode using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd>, and very quickly press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> <kbd>q</kbd> wanting to quit, every time I will end with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> dropped for unknown reason and a pending q.

I tried starting vim with `-w` to record typed keys and found there are a few occurrences of this key sequences `` <80>ý` `` interleaved with my typed keys in the recorded file.

After some experiment I found if I comment out this line `set updatetime=100` (which will set it back to default value 4000 ms i.e. 4s) in my vimrc, the <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> will not be dropped. However there are still some similar `<80>ýa` sequences after my pressed <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> in the recorded file. <del>And if I start vim as `vim -u NONE`, no such sequenced is recorded.</del>

<del>Further binary searching the source, the strange sequence seem to occur after `defaults.vim` has set `set nocompatible`. I read doc about `'compatible'` and `'cpoptions'` and didn't find anything relevant.</del>

I can now reproduce this `<80>ýa` randomly after <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> in pure `vim -u NONE` without setting anything, both inside and outside of tmux, using XShell or Ubuntu's native terminal.

What is causing this? How can I stop Vim from producing this code sequences?

ps: I'm using XShell to ssh to a ubuntu server in my local VMware and running vim in tmux. 
ý is decimal value 253 viewed with `ga` and `'fileencoding'` is `latin1`

Comment: I guess the recorded keys with `-w` option is not exactly the keys having been pressed, or at least not the original code sequence vim has received. I recorded similar `<80>kP` for PageUp key while ctrl-v PageUp gives `^[[5~`. May be this `<80>` stuff is vim's internal representation of keys. But I still don't know why in my case of ctrl-[ there is some extra code sequences being produced after ctrl-[.